# Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet: "nonce too low"

Tags: ether, rinkeby, faucets

I'm trying to use the Rinkeby Faucet to get ether for testing/development purposes. I've made a public Google Plus post with my account address but when I select the amount of ether I want, a message at the top of the screen says "nonce too low". Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmmm, I don't think you are doing anything wrong, I have the same problem using any link.

Usually a nonce issue is related to a sync issue, maybe the faucet is running behind.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually built a faucet [here](https://faucets.blockxlabs.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow)
One issue we faced was with scaling. We can't ask the blockchain for a nonce we have to track it manually because imagine if two developers ask for a transaction at the same time. One will fail if they get the same nonce from the blockchain. Thus we track it in our database and increment it when called. This does mean there is a small chance of having the nonce be wrong for whatever reason.